# Data is not being loaded in Jqwidget DataTable (JqDataTable)

Tags: umbraco7, jqwidget, backoffice

We needed datatable functionality for **backoffice** in our **Umbraco** based web application, so we decided to use **JqDataTable**.
JqDataTable is working fine the only issue we face is when we switch from one content node or tab to another, data inside table is not loaded.
Data is rendered once we change the pagination or we refresh our browser.

My Umbraco version is **7.9.1** and my JqWidget version is **8.3.2**

For more details I am using Ajax call to render data inside the JqDataTable.

Here is some code :

```
//Div inside HTML
<div id="jqtable"></div>

// Javascript code
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    GetMembers(function (returnValue) {           
        RenderDatatable(returnValue);
    });       
});

function GetMembers(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Members/GetMembers",
        success: function (response) {               
            var members = JSON.parse(response.members);
            callback(members);                
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
} 


function RenderDatatable(members) {
    var memberSource =
    {
        dataType: "array",
        dataFields: [
            { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'MiddleName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Contact', type: 'string' },                
            { name: 'Lastedited', type: 'date' }
        ],
        id: 'Id',
        localData: members
    };
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(memberSource);

    $("#jqtable").jqxDataTable(
    {               
            width: 630,
            theme: 'metro',
            pageable: true,
            sortable: true,                
            filterable: true,
            showToolbar: true,
            altRows: true,                
            pagerButtonsCount: 8,
            toolbarHeight: 35,
            source: dataAdapter,
            columns: [
                { text: 'ID', editable: false, align: 'center', dataField: 'Id', width: 80 },
                { text: 'First Name', dataField: 'FirstName', align: 'center', width: 200 },
                { text: 'Middle Name', dataField: 'MiddleName', align: 'center', width: 200 },
                { text: 'Last Name', dataField: 'LastName', align: 'center', width: 200 },
                { text: 'Email', dataField: 'Email', align: 'center', width: 200 },
                { text: 'Contact', dataField: 'Contact', align: 'center', width: 200 },
                { text: 'Last Edited', editable: false, dataField: 'Lastedited', align: 'center', cellsFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }
            ]
        });
}
```

Comment: please share some code or what have you done till now

Comment: @MohitPatil I have added the code in my question.